# Drawing table borders in libgdx (Table.drawDebug())

Tags: libgdx

I tried using this method to show debug lines:

table.debug();
Table.drawDebug(stage);

except Table.drawDebug expects a parameter of type: ShapeRenderer. 
any direction would be great

Answer (score 0):

You may just use a `new ShapeRender()` as parameter if your code doesn't contain one.

Comment: I tried to cast stage (of type Stage) as a ShapeRender, but it was not possible

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `table.drawDebug()`, just `table.debug()` is enough

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this?

```
Table table;
Stage stage;

public void show() {
    table = new Table();
    table.debug();

    ...

    stage = new Stage(...);

    stage.add(table);
}


public void render(float delta) {  
    Table.drawDebug(stage);
}
```

You debug draw the entire stage, but only the elements where `debug()` was called initially to mark them for debugging.
I hope this helps you.

P.S. btw this is from the official TableLayout docs [here](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout#overview) which is a must read if you're gonna mess around with Tables (if you haven't done so already).